# Did we change the voting button formatting?

Tags: discussion, bug

Recently, I was looking at a question, and these are the voting buttons:

[image: Image of current voting buttons]

I have a page, opened earlier today, which shows different formatting.

[image: Image of voting buttons this morning]

Was there an intentional change?

Comment: It has to be intentional. Nobody could make something that looks *that bad* by accident

Comment: @Valorum: I just noticed that they didn't change the comment voting buttons, so now they no longer match the Q/A voting buttons. *Yuck* to that!

Comment: See this, it was changed network-wide: [We are graduating the updated button styling for vote arrows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was an intentional change by SE to "graduate" the voting button styles across the network. You can see the main meta post for it here: [We are graduating the updated button styling for vote arrows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389359/345161)

> ### Update
>
> This experiment has been graduated. The new styling for vote arrows is now live across the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Ugh.  Can't win for losing, or something like that.  Way too visually heavy now, more prominent than the _actual_ text of the question!  I'm tempted to downvote your answer just because I don't like it. :D

Comment: @DavidW - The persistent complaint has been a lack of voting. I think the idea is to make the buttons bigger and more obvious so that people will use them more.

Comment: See here for ideas how to avoid this ugliness:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389564/how-do-i-change-vote-arrow-buttons-back

Comment: The buttons are so repulsive I feel like never clicking on them anymore.

Comment: @Valorum Oh...you have no idea... ;-)

Comment: Did they recently added a dark mode version?

Comment: @Clockwork Looks like they changed it so user's own votes would be actually visible.